# Removing string from string where part of the string can be a number in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I want to remove part of a string from another string where the part I want to remove has a number in it.

The string is my url and the part I want to remove is the page and page number
ex.

```
var url = www.mysite.com/?someparam=someparam&someparam=somparam&page=3
```

I want to remove the

```
&page=3
```

but the page can be 1,2,3,4,etc

I know I can do this by string replace like

```
var str = "mystring&page=1";
var res = str.replace("&page=1", "");
```

but this only works with a static number like 1, and I want it to work with any number

Answer (score 4):

Use a regular expressions with [`\d+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-digit) to match any number of one or more digits:

```js
function removePage(url) {
  return url.replace(/([?&])page=\d+(&?)/, function(p1, p2, p3) {
    return p2 === '?' ? '?' : p3;
  });
}

console.log(removePage('www.mysite.com/?someparam=someparam&someparam=somparam&page=6'));

console.log(removePage('www.mysite.com/?someparam=someparam&someparam=somparam&page=3&cats'));

console.log(removePage('www.mysite.com/?page=59&someparam=someparam&someparam=somparam'));
```